# store variable value between program execution in c#

Tags: c#, console-application

I have 2 console applications.

Application_B and Application_C. Both applications are collecting data from 
Application_A.

Lets say if I run Application_B first and it gets data from Application_A. At the same time if I run Application_C it should  display message that values have been filled, or something like that.

Comment: You have question marks, bit the previous sentence just describes context. What is your actual question?

Comment: To maintain some variable values  unless Application_B and Application_c 
 is running ?

Comment: you need a persistent storage to share something between apps. In case sql or nosql database is too much - xml or text file should work

Comment: yeah , i have created xml already .  I just want that till applications are running on task manager their data should store at some point

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It seems such an odd use case that there could be a better way of achieving what you want if we knew what the higher level goal is.

Comment: umm , you can say to avoid duplication.

Comment: @jahanzaibijaz so what's the question then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option that's probably optimal for your case:

**Save the value into a file in App_B and make App_C check for its presence and read it.**

---

Detailed answer:

You need to do two things:

- Save the value somewhere or otherwise make it available for reading from App_C
- Signal App_C of the event

There is a multitude of possible solutions that include:

- the simplest: save the value into a file (if it's an entire structure, probably by [serializing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843(v=vs.110).aspx) it) and make App_C check for its presence
- if the value must only be available while App_B is running, the latter can provide the means to read it via [IPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx). App_C then can check for App_B's process and/or for the communication channel's (e.g. a named pipe's) availability.

Comment: Thanks, can you please make it more simple? I would be thankful.

Comment: @jahanzaibijaz ignore everything except "save the value into a file and make App_C check for its presence" - that'd be as simple as it can be.

Comment: @jahanzaibijaz  Due to SO's quality standards, I need to outline all options, even if you'll probably only need one.

Comment: @jahanzaibijaz emphasized the option

Comment: I am trying to implement it. will let you know. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you reading the Application Domain concept before your development phase. Here is an extract.
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/application-domains

> Operating systems and runtime environments typically provide some form
>   of isolation between applications. For example, Windows uses processes
>   to isolate applications. This isolation is necessary to ensure that
>   code running in one application cannot adversely affect other,
>   unrelated applications. Application domains provide an isolation
>   boundary for security, reliability, and versioning, and for unloading
>   assemblies. Application domains are typically created by runtime
>   hosts, which are responsible for bootstrapping the common language
>   runtime before an application is run.

There are also some solutions for your problem that you can take advantage.
Using a shared repository can be a good solution. This Repository can be a file or a database.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16649419)

Comment: @VahidFarahmandian Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear but it seems `Application_A` is getting/generating data which `Application_B` or `Application_C` can collect. If one of them `(B/C)` has already collected data then other should show a message like 'data already collected' or 'no more data'.

`Application_A` must provide two things:

1. Store data somewhere. This can be protected for concurrent access. You can think of using Mutex.
2. A flag : This to indicate if more data is available. You can reset once data has been read by either B/C.

You can keep data at global place from where B/C can collect and A will write OR data can be maintained at C which will be passed to B/C after request. But for that you have to decide about protocol for inter-process communication.

Comment: Thanks, well yes. Application A is generating the data using xml File.
and app B/C accessing app_A